# pre_get_posts action: Search by post_title and post_content with different search phrase in the same query

Tags: search

How to set one search field to search in post_title and an another search field to search in post_content only, using "set" method in pre_get_post action?

Answer (score 2):

1. Adding the following code in functions.php customize WP search for `title` only

`function search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( empty( $search ) )
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';
    $search =
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
        $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }
    if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_title_only' );`

2. Search in `post content` is default search option in WP.

Comment: From your answer my conclusion is: pre_get_post action can't do what I want. But I didn't understand how can I differentiate two fields and say to WP that phrase_1 is for post_title only and phrase_2 is for post_content only, if I use field_name_1 and field_name_2 in search form? Or I must always use default search field and add new one for title? How can I then limit the default search field only for post_content?

Comment: You haven't differentiate two fields in search form. One field will search posts. But, if a checkbox or something like that checked, filter that search by  title only.  Else, search default, which search on post content only. Can I share idea?

Comment: But I want to differentiate two fields, one for each of two main searchable  post table fields. If this is not possible without writing custom sql then the idea to alter the query through hooks fails. If you have an idea, please share it. Thanks.

Comment: two field with two search form? Please share your design for better understanding. I assume that you want a search like https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/06-wordpress_advanced_search_form_2-preview-opt.png. Is it?

Comment: No no no. One search form with two search fields. One for post_title and one for post_content. I want to use pre_get_posts to alter wp_query. If pre_get_posts action can't do the job, how to solve?

Comment: Rightnow, I can't have exact code how to create your required form in WP. But, it gives us some idea how can get it. https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/build-your-own-custom-wordpress-search/